# Playing multiple tracks of audio online

Tags: android, ios, audio, web, media-player

My team and I are nearly done developing a music application for iPhone and Android that allows users to create their own music, built by playing and overlapping sampled sounds (up to 16 at a time).  We are looking for a way to allow users to share these songs by embedding an audio player in our website which will (like the Android and iPhone applications already do) take the songs, which are expressed as a string representing pitch, duration, start time, and instrument, and convert them into a single playable audio file (any format).

We have looked into SoundManager 2 and WebAudio, and have run into the same problem with both: stopping sounds creates beeping or popping sounds that cannot be removed.  Does anyone know of another framework or API that we should look into? A little googling also made sfplay stand out, but there isn't very much documentation on it.  Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are still a lot of problems with javascript/html5 audio. WebAudio is very powerful but not very portable. Soundmanager 2 is less powerful, but more portable. You should not be hearing clicks/discontinuities with either library unless you are doing something wrong, but there are problems with synchronization and so on with browser-based audio.

That's why most people doing "serious" audio on the web are using java applets or flash, which won't work on devices.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is a post we made previously regarding the specifics of our problem, but it has gotten no response.  Any ideas?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927302/soundmanager2-distortion-when-stopping-sound

Comment: I posted an answer, but I don't follow your code well enough to know if it's right.